# What does (button) mean?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner at Java, and have come across this line of code:

```
Button orderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.order);
```

What does the `(Button)` mean when it is inside the parenthesis?

What is the term for putting it inside like that?

Answer (score 6):

It is a type cast. You are casting the result to typeof(Button)

Comment: When is type casting necessary? What would happen if this line did not use it?

Comment: @user1389811: This is best illustrated with an example: If you have `Animal` and a derived type `Dog`, and you have a function that returns the type `Animal` but you *know* (for some reason) that the value it's returning to you is actually an instance of `Dog` and the variable you want to store the result in is of type `Dog`, you'd need the typecast: `Dog d = (Dog)getTheAnimal();` The converse is not true: `Animal a = getADog();` because you can assign descendant types (`Dog`) to ancestor-typed (`Animal`) variables without a cast.

Comment: @user1389811 you should try to run the code with out the type cast in there. I assume your code will spit an error saying something like "Type ERROR: cannot convert type(View Object) to Type(Button) " ... Casting forces the compiler to take a object and look at it as a different object

Comment: @user1389811: Following on from my comment above: There are other reasons for casting that relate to primitives: For instance, when you have a value in an `int` that you know is small enough to fit in a `byte` and for some reason you want to do that: `byte b = (byte)i;`

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of casting is to allow the execution environment and the IDE to know what the type of the object that is being returned by findViewById(R.id.order);

findViewById(R.id.order) does not return a specific type but a generic object. Since Button contains methods that are relevant to the item referenced by the object you need to tell it its type so that the new variable orderButton will have access to the correct methods.

This is a simple sample

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1170

Answer (score 1):

it is a [typecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).  The `findViewById` returns a `View` object, but you need a `Button` object.  the `(Button)` casts the View into a Button

Answer (score 1):

This is called **type-casting**.  The object returned by `findViewById(R.id.order);` is likely something that `Button` extends from.  Whoever wrote the code believes that the object returned by that function call is actually an instance of `Button`, so he is type-casting the return value of the function into an instance of `Button`.